# how to write last inserted data first on a excelsheet?

Tags: java, mongodb

i am writing mongodb data on a excelsheet using apache poi but its writing first inserted data on a first row of a excel but i need last inserted data on a first row i want to print last to first on excelsheet can someone help me how to do that this is my code.

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Sheet1");
    //HSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("Excel Sheet");
    XSSFRow rowhead;
    rowhead = sheet.createRow(0);
    rowhead.createCell(0).setCellValue("Employee ID");
    rowhead.createCell(1).setCellValue("Name");
    rowhead.createCell(2).setCellValue("Phone Number");
    rowhead.createCell(3).setCellValue("Domain");
    rowhead.createCell(4).setCellValue("Address");


    try {

        // To connect to mongodb server
        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);

        // Now connect to your databases
        DB db = mongoClient.getDB("test");
        System.out.println("Connect to database successfully");

        DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("testCollection");
        System.out.println("Collection mycol selected successfully");

        DBCursor cursor = collection.find();
        int i = 1;
        while (cursor.hasNext()) {
            DBObject o = cursor.next();
            //String fname = (String) o.get("Employee ID") ; 
            String lname = (String) o.get("Name");
            String sid = (String) o.get("Phone Number");
            String prg = (String) o.get("Domain");
            String lvl = (String) o.get("Address");

            Row row = sheet.createRow(i);
            row.createCell(0).setCellValue(lname);
            row.createCell(1).setCellValue(sid);
            row.createCell(2).setCellValue(prg);
            row.createCell(3).setCellValue(lvl);
            i++;

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
    }

    try (FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("datasheet.xlsx")) {
        workbook.write(outputStream);
    }

}
```

Comment: use `cursor = collection.find().sort("keyName")` to sort the result as you want before writing them in the excel sheet

Comment: try reversing the loop with length to 0

Answer (score 0):

If it is currently creating the Excel in the exact reverse order of how you'd like to see the rows, you can create a Deque object (myDeque) containing DBObjects and

```
myDeque.addFirst(o);
```

until you are done with the "cursor.hasNext()" loop.
After that you can set

```
DBObject o = myDeque.removeFirst();
```

and you can iterate while adding the row to Excel until the Deque object is empty.

As requested, code below:

```
import java.util.Deque;
//Other Imports here

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Sheet1");
    //HSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("Excel Sheet");
    XSSFRow rowhead;
    rowhead = sheet.createRow(0);
    rowhead.createCell(0).setCellValue("Employee ID");
    rowhead.createCell(1).setCellValue("Name");
    rowhead.createCell(2).setCellValue("Phone Number");
    rowhead.createCell(3).setCellValue("Domain");
    rowhead.createCell(4).setCellValue("Address");


    try {

        // To connect to mongodb server
        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);

        // Now connect to your databases
        DB db = mongoClient.getDB("test");
        System.out.println("Connect to database successfully");

        DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("testCollection");
        System.out.println("Collection mycol selected successfully");

        DBCursor cursor = collection.find();
        Deque<DBObject> stack = new Deque<>();
        int i = 1;
        while (cursor.hasNext()) {
            DBObject o = cursor.next();
            stack.addFirst(o);
        }
        while(!stack.isEmpty()){
            o = stack.removeFirst();
            //String fname = (String) o.get("Employee ID") ; 
            String lname = (String) o.get("Name");
            String sid = (String) o.get("Phone Number");
            String prg = (String) o.get("Domain");
            String lvl = (String) o.get("Address");

            Row row = sheet.createRow(i);
            row.createCell(0).setCellValue(lname);
            row.createCell(1).setCellValue(sid);
            row.createCell(2).setCellValue(prg);
            row.createCell(3).setCellValue(lvl);
            i++;

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
    }

    try (FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("datasheet.xlsx")) {
        workbook.write(outputStream);
    }

}
```

Comment: it is not creating the excel in the reverse order i want my excel sheet in reverse order its writing excel in exact form as it is in database i need last inserted data on a first row ??

Comment: Yes, this should accomplish that as it is putting these on a "Last In, First Out" (LIFO) stack.  This means the Last thing written in the Database will become the first row on your Excel sheet.

Comment: could you please implement this in my above code because i am not able to do this...??

Answer (score 0):

it is working fine for Last in first out **cursor.sort(new BasicDBObject("_id", -1));**